# Is there a way to add other columns to the list display in the page admin?

Tags: wagtail

Currently, in the wagtail admin for a page, it lists the Order, Title, Updated, Page Type, and Status.  I would like to add an extra column for a property from my custom page model.

I would have thought that if there isn't a built-in method, I could at least overextend a template, or simply append something to the page title?

My situation is that I have created a blog page that has a date field.  It is only that I wish to show.

My google-fu has failed me entirely on finding an answer as I'm sure this must have been discussed before.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't currently an 'official' way for customising the columns in the listing. However, for displaying the date alongside the page title, you could make use of the `get_admin_display_title` method added in Wagtail 1.8: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.get_admin_display_title